# Rails - controller.controller_name inside view - where is controller object defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While reading "Agile Web Development with Rails 4.0" I've encountered the line that I can't fully understand. Inside `application.html.erb` author sets the `class` attribute of `body` tag in the following way:

```
<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>
```

I know that there is an `ActionController::Metal#controller_name` method in Rails, which returns the underscored last part of the controller's name, I understand it. What confuses me is the `controller` object from which this method is called. I've searched through Rails API and haven't found any methods called `controller` that would return the instance of current controller. Where is it defined or where did it come from?

Comment: Hmmm.  Normally the controller name would be found via params[:controller] since the name of the controller and action are sent via the params hash.  Are you sure this was not a custom method in a helper file?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure it was not a custom - I've checked this part of application and there was no definition for `controller` method. Btw rails guides mention `controller_name` and advise to use it instead of `params` hash - section 4.3 of  [controller overview](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper` module that takes care of delegating certain methods to the controller. Check in the Rails source code at [`rails/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b326e82dc012d81e9698cb1f402502af1788c1e9/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb)